# C++11 typedef alias compile error

Tags: c++, c++11, alias, typedef

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
```

I know, this was asked several times before, but I didn't find the answer. Usually they say that a semicolon is missing in one of the header files. But it's not the case now. And of course I use the `-std=c++0x` flag

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


template <typename T>
using stringpair = std::pair<std::string, T>;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler and version?

Answer (score 3):

Your error [is caused](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9184f7297405d5e4) by the fact that [template aliases with `using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) is a C++11 feature and your compiler does not support it. You should add the corresponding flags at compilation. Those most likely are:

```
-std=c++11
```

(at least for `g++` and `clang++`).

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5aa770574bd5a0d)

Otherwise your compiler does not support them yet. GCC [supports them from 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Comment: I know, I'm compiling, with this option

Comment: @balping, I'm sorry, but this is the only way you can reproduce that error. So, you are evidently not compiling with that option.

Comment: @balping, Perhaps your compiler does not support it yet. As far as I know, all of MSVC, GCC, and Clang support this feature in their latest versions.

Comment: My compiler, gcc-4.6, does not support these `using` aliases even in C++11 mode.  I know 4.8.1 supports it, but  my guess is that the OP is also using an earlier version of the compiler with incomplete C++11 support.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson, template aliases [were introduced in 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Comment: On the side note OP should also #include<utility> in his program as std::pair has been used in the program.

Comment: Both template aliases and `-std=c++11` were introduced in the GCC 4.7 series, earlier versions used the flag `-std=c++0x` to enable support for the "next" version of C++. So if a (g++) compiler accepts `-std=c++11`, it should also accept template aliases.

Comment: The problem may be the version. I'm using 4.6 and I'm updating now